# Error: Undeclared Label

Tags: objective-c

I'm following this tutorial: [link](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/)

But, at this part:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
}
```

Xcode says that `longitudeLabel` and `latitudeLabel` weren't declared. But they were declared at ViewController.h as follows:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitudeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longitudeLabel;
```

Someone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Haven't done ios in a while but don'y you have to `@sythesize` them

Comment: @aaronman The need to use `@synthesize` is obsolete with newer versions of the compiler.